# Kotlin function type instead functional interface lambda

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I'm struggling in kotlin to get opposite of functional interface in java. I have the following problem.

```
class ResultReceiverTest(handler : Handler) : ResultReceiver(handler) {

    fun onResult(result : (resultCode : Int, resultData: Bundle) -> Unit){
        // result() how to receive values from onReceiveResult() method?
    }

    override fun onReceiveResult(resultCode: Int, resultData: Bundle){
        // how to call onResult from here?
        // I want to pass resultCode, resultData parameter to onResult function
    }
}
```

I have the following situation, first of all `onReceiveResult` is called then I want to pass the value of `onReceiveResult`'s paramets to the `onResult` so there I could be able to pass the value to `result()` which is being implemented by the following class.

```
class StartService {
    private var resultReceiverTest = ResultReceiverTest(Handler())

    init{
        resultReceiverTest.onResult({a, b -> something()})
    }


    fun something(){}
}
```

So how I can deliver the value from `onReceiveResult` to `onResult` ? I know the functional interface and anonymous class solution in kotlin. But I want to achieve it using lambda which will be helpful for my understanding about lambda too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a property to hold the handler.

```
class ResultReceiverTest(handler : Handler) : ResultReceiver(handler) {
    private var resultHandler: ((resultCode : Int, resultData: Bundle) -> Unit)? = null

    fun onResult(result : (resultCode : Int, resultData: Bundle) -> Unit){
        resultHandler = result
    }

    override fun onReceiveResult(resultCode: Int, resultData: Bundle){
        resultHandler?.invoke(resultCode, resultData)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing error on 2nd line `null`. I'm unable to assign null.

Comment: Found the solution. I have to round the type in parantheses. `((resultCode : Int, resultData: Bundle) -> Unit)?`

Comment: how I can call the `resultCode`? it is showing error to use explicit `?.invoke()`

Comment: Why do you want to call `resultCode`? It's a parameter and you just simply can't call a parameter.

Comment: Sorry I was talking about `resultHandler`

Answer (score 1):

Why not do something like this? Provide the on result callback during initialization:

```
class ResultReceiverTest(handler: Handler, private val onResult: (Int, Bundle) -> Unit) : ResultReceiver(handler) {
  override fun onReceiveResult(resultCode: Int, resultData: Bundle) {
    onResult(resultCode, resultData)
  }
}

// Do it with a function reference
class StartService {

  private var resultReceiverTest = ResultReceiverTest(Handler(), this::doSomethingWithResult)

  fun doSomethingWithResult(resultCode: Int, resultData: Bundle) {
    println(resultCode)
  }
}

// OR DO IT INLINE
class StartService {

  private var resultReceiverTest = ResultReceiverTest(Handler()) { resultCode, resultData -> println(resultCode) }

}
```

Comment: how I can call the `resultCode`? it is showing error to use explicit `?.invoke()`

Comment: What's the error? The above code compiles just fine in Kotlin 1.1.3

Comment: Sorry that was typo. I was talking about `resultReceiverTest` function